# How to set UISlider value so it will be always at the center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uislider

I am looking for UISlider value which will set the indicator at the center.

iContrastSlider.minimumValue = 85;
iContrastSlider.maximumValue = 200;

So, which value I need to set,so that indicator will be always @ center.  I tried with all values but it always start from 0 as shown in image.

[image]

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code

```
float centerValue = ((iContrastSlider.maximumValue - iContrastSlider.minimumValue) / 2)+iContrastSlider.minimumValue;
[iContrastSlider setValue:centerValue animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simple math to calculate the average:

```
float centerValue = ((iContrastSlider.minimumValue + iContrastSlider.maximumValue) / 2) + iContrastSlider.minimumValue;
[iContrastSlider setValue:centerValue animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

add this into your slider
iContrastSlider.minimumValue = 85/200;
iContrastSlider.maximumValue = 200/200;

`iContrastSlider.value = 115/200;`

This will shows your slider value to center